# How do I pass form data from one HTML page to another HTML page using ONLY javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm a beginner in Javascript and my professor has only taught us HTML5 and Javascript so far so I can't show up using PHP lol. So far I have a page with a form where a user can input data and I have an external javascript file that has two functions to verify passwords and auto-populate delivery information from billing information. In the form tag I have onsubmit="return verifyPswd()" and that works fine calling it from outside of the HTML file. But what I'm trying to do is now pull the form data either from the URL (I'm using method="GET") or some other way and display the data on my third HTML page which is the Results page. I have tried everything, even moving the javascript code into the first HTML page and absolutely nothing has worked so I signed up for SO.

Here's parts of my code I think is important for accurate help. Thanks so much in advance.

My form html page:

```
<body>
<h1>OrderUp!</h1>
<form name=orderup method="get" action="Results.html" onsubmit="return verifyPswd()">
...ALL THE FORM CODE...
<input id= "order" type="submit" value="Place Order"></center></input>
```

My results html page:

```
<body>
<h1>OrderUp!</h1>
<center><p id = "success">Your form has been successfully submitted!</p>
</center>
</body>
```

I guess the hardest part or most confusing part is where exactly do I call the function to display the entries?! In the results page or the form page? And can you have two onsubmits? I'm frustrated.

Comment: Use javascript cookies

Comment: put your javascript code

Comment: Other than cookies which is an option you can also use web storage https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Answer (score 2):

Without server code your data will not persist across your pages, so you need a global store, where they each have access. You can't simply grab a javascript file, and set variables, because when the next page loads them, it will not view those changes.

I highly recommend (for now), storing your values in the browser's session storage, or local storage. The data will persist as long as you're on the domain.

Here's how you do it in javascript:

```
// Save data to sessionStorage
sessionStorage.setItem('key', 'value');

// Get saved data from sessionStorage
var data = sessionStorage.getItem('key');

// Remove saved data from sessionStorage
sessionStorage.removeItem('key');

// Remove all saved data from sessionStorage
sessionStorage.clear();
```

Session storages will only keep values until your browser closes, localstorages will be kept if you close your browser and return.

For local storage, you can simply replace the above "sessionStorage" with "localStorage"

Please check the reference here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

Answer (score 1):

You can save your items using localstorage and get them in other page :

```
localStorage.setItem("yourDataKey", "This can be anything, simple string, or a complex object");
```

and get it back in other page :

```
var myDataFromFirstPage = localStorage.getItem("yourDataKey");
```

if you need to remove it, you can do it as well :

```
localStorage.removeItem("yourDataKey");
```

You can pass any type of data, it can be a simple string or a complex object.